# Как сделать чтобы высота "textarea" зависело от контекста?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать чтобы высота `textarea` зависело от контекста?

```css
textarea {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea>
  One advanced diverted domestic repeated bringing you old. Possible procured her trifling laughter thoughts property she met way. Companions shy had solicitude favourable own. Which could saw guest man now heard but. Lasted my coming uneasy marked so should. Gravity letters it amongst herself dearest an windows by. Wooded ladies she basket season age her uneasy saw. Discourse unwilling am no described dejection incommode no listening of. Before nature his parish boy. 
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С помощью [scrollHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight) можно получить высоту элемента, с учётом контента. Полученное значение выставляем свойству `height`.

*ps.* `6px` вычел, так как *4* - это `padding` и 2 - `border` (верх/низ). *Это значение ставьте, как потребуется. Зависит от стилей.*

```js
textarea = document.getElementById('area');
textarea.style.height = (textarea.scrollHeight - 6) + 'px';
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  resize: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="area">One advanced diverted domestic repeated bringing you old. Possible procured her trifling laughter thoughts property she met way. Companions shy had solicitude favourable own. Which could saw guest man now heard but. Lasted my coming uneasy marked so should. Gravity letters it amongst herself dearest an windows by. Wooded ladies she basket season age her uneasy saw. Discourse unwilling am no described dejection incommode no listening of. Before nature his parish boy</textarea>
```

В случаи, если требуется менять высоту в зависимости от набираемого текста, то можно воспользоваться событием *oninput*:

```js
textarea = document.getElementById('area');

textarea.oninput = function() {
  autoHeight();
};

function autoHeight() {
  textarea.style.height = (textarea.scrollHeight - 6) + 'px';
}

autoHeight();
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  resize: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="area">One advanced diverted domestic repeated bringing you old. Possible procured her trifling laughter thoughts property she met way. thoughts property</textarea>
```